# Add role cores without restarting role service

Tags: solr

We are using bitnami solr on Windows server.

We create solr cores with powershell which basically creates folders and config.

Every time we perform this, role service is required for new cores to be reflected.

Is there way to add cores without having to restart solr cores?

Comment: What is a `role service`? You don't have to restart Solr or their cores to add new cores to the server. Is your scripting copying new cores into the Solr directory and you want Solr to pick up the new cores?

Comment: Yep correct, add cores without role service restart

Comment: Use [the CoreAdmin API to create the cores](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/coreadmin-api.html). That will change the state of your currently running Solr instance. You give it the path to the core you've just created.